# Using generic views with slashes in the primary key

Tags: django

I'm making an application where the primary key for one of the models contains slashes. For example, `xx/xxxxxxx/xx`. This presents a problem when I'm writing the URL conf, as I don't want to lock it down to containing only a certain number of slashes, but I want to be able to have child views as well... i.e.

- `http://example.com/xx/xxxxxxx/xx/`
- `http://example.com/xx/xxxxxxx/xx/edit/`

Currently my urlconf looks like

```
programme_patterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$',
        login_required(views.ProgrammeDetailView.as_view()),
        name='programme_detail'),
    url(r'^edit/$',
        login_required(views.ProgrammeFormView.as_view()),
        name='programme_edit'),
)

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^programmes/?P<pk>.*?/.*?/.*?)/',
        include(programme_patterns))
)
```

Having the primary key slashes in the URL also makes me feel uncomfortable as it's unsemantic, this should look like one 'directory' not a nest of three.

I was wondering if there's a way to transform the primary key for use in the URL, for example, replace the slashes with underscores. I just can't think of a way to do this without breaking the reverse URL machinery.

Answer (score 0):

from the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/):

> Model.get_absolute_url() Define a get_absolute_url() method to tell
>   Django how to calculate the canonical URL for an object. To callers,
>   this method should appear to return a string that can be used to refer
>   to the object over HTTP.
>
> For example:

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return "/people/%i/" % self.id
```

> (Whilst this code is correct and simple, it may not be the most
>   portable way to write this kind of method. The reverse() function is
>   usually the best approach.)
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> def get_absolute_url(self):
>     from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
>     return reverse('people.views.details', args=[str(self.id)])
> ```

Comment: But say I want to do `reverse('programme_edit', pk=instance.pk)`

Comment: You can add to your model your own method that returns the pk with underscores intead of slashes or you could use get_absolute_url (which is nice because it also works well with the admin site too)

Comment: What would be the best way to modify the generic views to take this different ID?

Comment: That's an interesting question. My initial thought is that it probably also relies on get_absolute_url, but I'm not entirely sure of that. I did find in the docs that you might need to configure your own get() call (see here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/class-based-views/), so your best bet is to either write the views yourself or test around to see what works with the generic views